# Structuring Dissertation as Thesis Rather than "Standard" Bachelor's Structure

Tags: thesis, united-kingdom, bachelor

I'm in the process of developing a quantum random number generator utilising novel mechanisms that haven't yet been implemented in commercial products in an effort to achieve better randomness and a higher bitrate. This is for my Bachelor of Engineering degree in the UK.

My university doesn't stipulate any particular format, and since it's just a BEng (not an MEng) doesn't require a literature review. However, since I intend on pursuing a PhD immediately following the completion of my BEng, I feel it would be beneficial to structure the dissertation as a mini-thesis broken into relevant chapters with names that I find appropriate rather than using the more standard dissertation template simply using stock headings (research, evaluation, etc.). I'm also planning on doing a literature review.

Do you think this is appropriate or could it backfire?

If it's relevant, I'll be using Latex `book` rather than `article`, to give you an idea of the formatting.

Comment: A brief conversation with the faculty person advising you on this project would be in order. Maybe you are unaware of requirements on content or style or some such. Presumably this will be the person, or one of the people, evaluating your work to decide if it satisfies the degree requirements. So chat with them about form and content.

Answer (score 3):

LaTex is irrelevant for the question. But there is no reason not to do it your way provided that there aren't rules that prevent it. But your advisor is the best guide here.

In fact, since you intend to move to doctoral studies the experience would probably be worth any additional effort.

But you need to get some assurance that you won't get late push-back on it from anyone. Again, your advisor, or other faculty should be able to give the best advice.

Comment: I did think it would be largely irrelevant, I mainly included it so that it would be obvious the sort of format changes I'm talking about. Thanks for your advice.